# How to update state into Provider context in class in React

Tags: reactjs

i have a problemn, i need to pass an array to class DragAndDropProvider but not working, i can see value in console log but not is possible update state with value, received error as:

*Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.*

moment in that i call the class
Index

```
 const documents = UseGetDocuments();
    const { state, setItemsArray } = useContext(DragAndDropContext);
    setItemsArray(documents);
```

DragAndDropProvider

```
export class DragAndDropProvider extends Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            moveItem: this.moveItem,
            setItems: this.setItems
        };
    }

    an_independent_function(documents: any) {
        console.log(documents);
        this.setState({ items: documents })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <DragAndDropContext.Provider
                value={
                    {
                        state: this.state,

                        setItemsArray: (documents: any) => {
                            this.an_independent_function(documents);
                        },
                    }

                }>
                {this.props.children}
            </DragAndDropContext.Provider>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Class components you need to bind 'this' for it to work in your callback function.

```
constructor(props: any) {
  ...

  this.an_independent_function = this.an_independent_function.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: What about the following code for your DragAndDropContext.Provider value prop:

`value={{
  state: this.state,
  setItemsArray: this.an_independent_function,
}}`

Comment: this is returned: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.